# Comparing two characters and increment a counter

Tags: java

I am trying to compare to characters, but it doesn't work properly.

Here it is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AlternatingChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        //int n=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        String str=scan.nextLine();
        char c1, c2;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0,j=i+1;i<str.length()-1;i++,j++)
        {
             c1 = str.charAt(i);
             c2 = str.charAt(j);
            System.out.println(c1+"    "+c2);
            if(c1==c2){
                count=count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);

    }

}
```

And my output is

```
aaaa
a    a
a    a
a    a
0
```

I need to count value when every time it matches, please rectify my mistake.

Comment: `count=count++;` should be `count++`

Comment: I  added en explanation in the answer, couldn't explain in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
count=count++;
```

to

```
count++;
```

Because the first one is assigning the initial value to `count` every time. Why?

Your code is equivalent to:

```
int oldCounter = 0; 
counter = counter + 1;
counter = oldCounter;
```